# Communicating with a website via usb connection to a Xamarin.Android app

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.android, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a specific requirement where an Android device cannot have any WIFI/Internet connection. However, the android device can be connected to a Windows machine (that has network capabilities) with an USB cable.

Is there a way to transfer data from the android app(Xamarin.Android) to the Web Application(.Net Core 2 )? Maybe some way for me to hit the controllers via USB connection (Or alternatively bluetooth if this option is not available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to transfer data from the android app(Xamarin.Android) to the Web Application(.Net Core 2 )?

Generally, this is done by certain tool, which enables the TCP transactions between your android device and your PC. ex: [Port Forwarding](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server).